# Верстка формы

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

В форме присутствует поле `textarea`, поле обернуто в див, и для него задан фон, но при этом все равно в правом нижнем углу у `textarea` остается треугольник (который каждый браузер отрисовывает по своему) http://jsfiddle.net/TANAn/12/
Как от него избавиться?
Также не получается задать для текста `placeholder` свои параметры шрифта и цвета, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Треугольник получилось отключить, задав

```
.addComments form textarea{
    resize: none;
    }
```

Для содержимого textarea написан скрипт

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addComments form .message').html('Your Message...');

    $('.addComments form .message').focus(function(){
    $('.addComments form .message').empty();
    });
    });
</script>
```

но почему-то не происходит очистки textarea при фокусе. подскажите, почему?

вот новый вариант верстки http://jsfiddle.net/TANAn/16/

Comment: А это зачем?    $('.addComments form .message').html('Your Message...');Для работы **placeholder**-а не нужны никакие дополнительные скрипты. "Стартовое" значение пропадает, когда начинаешь вводить данные в поле. Другое дело, что не во всех браузерах он работает. А если кроссбраузерное решение нужно, то **placeholder** как бы ни к чему, а [всё можно в JS сделать](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/TANAn/19/).

Comment: P.S. Кстати, методами **.html()** и **.empty()**, вы попросту "убиваете" **textarea**. Уже после использования **.html()** - его просто не существует.

Comment: @Deonis а как задать стили для того текста, который по умолчанию отображается в textarea ? сейчас текст выводится с стилями браузера по умолчанию, а мне нужно сделать, чтобы он по внешнему виду был аналогичен текстам в инпутах.

Comment: а, всё, получилось со стилями

Answer (score 1):

Для визуализации `placeholder` используйте:

```
input:-moz-placeholder { ... }
input:-ms-input-placeholder { ... }
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { ... }
```

Comment: мне нужен placeholder не для инпутов, а для textarea

Comment: @Heidel, для textarea исправить аналогично :) http://jsfiddle.net/9Wb4T/